# Ball float valve in an overfilled tank

Tags: fluid-statics, flow

A ball float valve ([YT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=siyYJE7DdQM)) is used to stop inflow into a tank. A Ball floats up when the water level reaches close to the pipe, forcing the valve to close.

Consider a tank with an inlet (inlet A) with such a ball valve. Also suppose that there is another inlet (inlet B) to the tank. After inlet A is closed (and inflow from the corresponding source is gone), suppose a lot of water flows in from inlet B. Does the ball valve open and drain the liquid coming in from inlet B into inlet A? Or will the valve remain closed?

(Practical application: sump with inlet A with inflow coming in periodically *not continuously* from the municipal water supply, and inlet B coming from roof-top rain water harvesting.)

Comment: A picture would certainly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems more of an engineering question.

Anyway the valve should stay closed, as in an "overfilled" tank (I assume it means that the water level is above the ball) there is an even larger upward force on the ball, than in a "full" tank (when the ball floats on the top of the water). (Based on Archimedes' principle.) (Unless the stick holding the ball or some other parts of the system breaks, due to the high upward force. But it probably won't happen.)

Also you can easily test it before actual usage (just to be sure it will fit your needs).

Answer (score 1):

The A valve is connected to a higher pressure water supply in order for it to flow into the tank, so opening it again would only let more water in. The valve in the video will shut off the water supply at the desired level. If more water comes in from another source, such as source B, and the water level rises, the ball float will not rise further and will become submerged if the water level rises above it. However it would be simple to have either a gravity fed drain hole above the float level, or a water pump controlled by a separate float valve, set at the desired maximum level, attached to its electrical on / off switch.